# What is the rationale behind not having a writesome function for basic_ostream in the STL?

Tags: c++, stl, network-programming, iostream

While working on a network library I recently noticed that having a pendant to basic_streambuf::in_avail in conjunction with a writesome function would be pretty handy for asynchronous I/O.

I have searched the web and checked several C++ references if there is any function which meets these demands, but it seems I had no luck. The only source which mentions similar functionality is [Boost's Asio](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/basic_stream_socket/write_some.html) library, however the description clearly states that the function call will block until at least one byte has been sent which does not reflect my desired behaviour.

To elaborate on my question, I created a rough draft based on the C++ N3337 publication.

> **27.6.3.2.5  Put area [streambuf.pub.put]**
>
> `streamsize in_depart();`
>
> *Returns:* If a write position is available, returns `epptr() - pptr()`. Otherwise 
>   returns `showmanycp()`.
>
> **27.6.3.4.5  Put area [streambuf.virt.put]**
>
> `streamsize showmanycp();`
>
> *Returns:* An estimate of the number of characters which can be written to the sequence,
>   or `-1`. If it returns a positive value, then successive calls to `overflow()` will not
>   return `traits::eof()` until at least that number of characters have been written to the
>   stream. If `showmanycp()` returns `-1`, then calls to `overflow()`will fail.
>
> *Default behavior:* Returns zero.
>
> *Remarks:* Uses `traits::eof()`.
>
> **27.7.3.7        Unformatted output functions [ostream.unformatted]**
>
> `streamsize writesome(char_type* s, streamsize n);`
>
> *Effects:* Behaves as an unformatted output function (as described in 27.7.3.7, paragraph
>   1). After constructing a sentry object, if `!good()` calls`setstate(failbit)` which may
>   throw an exception, and return. Otherwise writes `n` characters designated by `s`. If
>   `rdbuf()->in_depart() == -1`, calls `setstate(badbit)` (which may throw
>   `ios_base::failure` (27.5.5.4)), and writes no characters;
>
> — If `rdbuf()->in_depart() == 0`, writes no characters.
>
> — If `rdbuf()->in_depart() > 0`, writes `min(rdbuf()->in_depart(), n))` characters.
>
> *Returns:* The number of characters written.

Comment: ehm... http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/basic_stream_socket/async_write_some.html ?

Comment: I don't look for a third-party solution, I'm rather interested in why there is no such function in the latest C++ standard. Thanks for the link though.

Comment: `in_avail()` is pretty much useless for sockets because the value it returns is stale.

Comment: @Markus If something is not in the standard then the 'rationale' is always that either noone has proposed it or that any proposals were rejected for various reasons.

Comment: @MaximYegorushkin, my socket streambuf is using FIONREAD in showmanyc. I assume there is something similar for Windows.

Comment: @Cubic Elaborating on your comment has there ever been any proposal regarding my question?

Answer (score 2):

I'd guess you misinterpret the meaning of `in_avail()` and `readsome()`: all these say is that the stream had read a block of data and there are still characters in the buffer. Yes, it could theoretically do something different but in particukar when reading from a network you don't know how much data is available until you tried reading it.

Similarily, there is no way to guarantee to be able to get rid of a y specific number of characters: what would `out.writesome(buf, n)` mean? If you want it to mean that you dumped `n` characters into `out`'s buffer, you can just create a suitable stream buffer and use `write()`. Guaranteeing that `n` bytes are sent with blocking, however, can't be done (at least, for `1 < n`). I guess you want the latter, though.

Comment: To reparaphrase my concerns there is no STL function similar to in_avail when writing which tells whether the next call to write will block or not. I'm not necessarily concerned about how many bytes I can write without blocking if at least one byte can be written in a single call to write.  
As AProgrammer mentioned there are certain ways to check if data is in avail on a socket which can be combined with showmanyc to prevent potential blocking. A call to select with zero timeout would at least tell you if there is pending data and if the socket is writeable.

Comment: Regarding your answer out.writesome(buf, n) may write as many bytes it can do without blocking. Similar to readsome it may set the stream's state to eofbit if the pendant to in_avail returns -1, write zero characters if n equals 0 or else write std::min(rdbuf()->in_avail_pendant(), n)).

Comment: @MarkusQuär: What I'm saying is that `readsome()` doesn't read: it pulls bytes from the buffer. `writesome()` symmetrically would put bytes into the buffer where they would be stuck until you call something which either blocks or may make no progress!

Comment: I'm a bit confused now, but `readsome()` internally calls `in_avail()` which in turn might call `showmanyc()` which returns  "An estimate of the number of characters available in the sequence, or -1." and "If it returns a positive value, then successive calls to underflow() will not return traits::eof() until at least that number of characters have been extracted from the stream. If showmanyc() returns -1, then calls to underflow() or uflow() will fail." (Quoted from C++ N3337 Draft 27.6.3.4.3) which eventually might lead to a read on the physical device.

Comment: Yes, this is correct: It *can* do more clever things sometimes. It is unlikely that it does, though. On a socket you know that you can read `n` bytes when you have read them. The only thing a socket might tell you is if it won't block when you try to read. Personnally, I wouldn't override `showmanyc()` on a socket.

Comment: Concluding from your comment it doesn't imply it's not feasible at all, though. Same applies to writing on a blocking socket if you stick to TCP as underlying transport protocol, since a call to `select()` with appropriate `fd_set` will tell you whether the socket is writeable or not. This may be used in conjunction with the proposal mentioned above.